# Telescoping understanding the exp. given in textbook

Tags: calculus

[image]

My problem is not understanding the end result. However I go about solving it in a different way. I do this:

[image]

Now I see that all the terms cancel out except 1 and $-\frac{1}{13}$, it is easy to see that this is is equal to 1- 1/2(n+1), hence you are left with the same term as in the solution. However my struggle is understanding how the text book has presented this. I have marked out in red what I do not get, and I am particularly confused with what is marked in blue,(Where does the 3 come from). Could someone please 
explain this?

Comment: That $\;2n-3\;$ is just to make things clearer (paradox, uh?), and it corresponds to the sum when the index $\;k=n-1\;$ :$$\frac12\left(\frac1{2(n-1)-1}-\frac1{2(n-1)+1}\right)=\frac12\left(\frac1{2n-3}-\frac1{2n-1}\right)$$ To make things clearer, the book wrote you the last two expressions, for $\;k=n-1\;$ and for $\;k=n\;$

Comment: Does K go from 2->inf or how does it work?

Comment: In the series yes. Well, from $\;1\rightarrow\infty\;$, but the above comment pointed to the partial sum $\;s_n\;$ part of which **you did** mark in red.

Comment: Would you be able to explain it in more detail I just do not get how this k is substituted in and which range it is taking.

Comment: Could you please write down **explicitly** what does $\;s_n\;$ mean? I'm afraid you either confuse or don't know the basic notations here.

Comment: I thought it was nth partial sum of geometric series?

Comment: What *geometric series* are you talking about? Anyway, $\;s_n\;$ is the $\;n$-th partial sum of your series (which is **not** a geometric one)